# Add user without signup form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a users signup form and once a users signs up he is redirected to users details forms.

user signup form.

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :email, class: "required" %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, required: true %>
      <%= f.label :password, class: "required" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, required: true %>
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, class: "required" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, required: true %>
      <%= f.submit 'Sign up' %>
<% end %>
```

user details forms

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :user_firstname, "First Name", class: "required"  %>
   <%= f.text_field :user_firstname, required: true %>
   <%= f.label :user_lastname, "Last Name", class: "required"  %>
   <%= f.text_field :user_lastname, required: true %>
   <%= f.submit 'Save' %>            
<% end %>
```

I want to add a feature so that admin can add a users who doesn't have a email and admin just adds a details in users details form and submits and user is created.
What I have done is, I have added a route and added a method in user controller and this is the error I am getting **There was an error adding family. Try again** . Please help me fix this

Routes

```
get 'adduser', to:'users#adduser'
post 'adduser', to:'users#create_user'
```

User controller

```
def adduser
  @user=User.new
end
def create_user
  @user=User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "User successfully added" redirect_to main_admin_path
  else
    flash[:danger] = "There was an error adding user. Try again" redirect_to main_admin_path
  end
end

<%= form_for(@user, url: adduser_path, :html => { multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
       <%= f.label :user_firstname, "First Name", class: "required"  %>
       <%= f.text_field :user_firstname, required: true %>
       <%= f.label :user_lastname, "Last Name", class: "required"  %>
       <%= f.text_field :user_lastname, required: true %>
       <%= f.submit 'Save' %>            
<% end %>
```

Validations

```
attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
before_create :confirmation_token
has_secure_password
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
validates_attachment :document
validates_confirmation_of :password
```

Comment: What is in your server log when you've got the error?

Comment: I am getting the error because of my validations. Check validations in the update

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU: you should _post_ the updates first, __then__ ping users about them.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry about that.

Comment: You can use `@user.save(validate: false)` in the controller if you really want to create users without email

Comment: Or you can add some boolean flag `created_by_admin` to these users and use a conditional validation, based on this flag. It is better, because in the first case you'll have invalid users in the db

Comment: @Vasilisa I think created by admin boolean is a good idea. Can You please help me on that.

Comment: @Vasilisa i have added a boolean field in the users forms added by admin. How do condition validations work.

Comment: You really don't need to store `created_by_admin` in the database. Simply make it an `attr_accessor` on the model. That will do the job without any schema changes.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, for logging purposes, and in order to figure out how a user was once created it seems like a good idea to somehow log/store the information about `created_by_admin`, but you're technically right that it can be an attr_accessor for the purposes of this code.

Comment: @EmilKampp yes, if, in future we need to see how the user was created, then we surely need to store it in database. In fact, in that case, we should store `created_by` and an actual ID of admin who created it. But, that all depends what OP needs in his application. :)

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I have used the option for created_by_admin but when I try to update the user that is created by admin. I am not able to save it. This is the error I am getting. No template found for UsersController#update, rendering head :no_content but I am about to update the users that are not created by admin.

Comment: @EmilKampp I have used the option for created_by_admin but when I try to update the user that is created by admin. I am not able to save it. This is the error I am getting. No template found for UsersController#update, rendering head :no_content but I am about to update the users that are not created by admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you need to create a migration and add a new column to the users table. I think it is better to keep info about admin creating in the db (if you don't want to store it, just add `:created_by_admin` to `attr_accessor` list instead of this step).

```
add_column :users, :created_by_admin, :boolean, default: false, null: false
```

Add this new field to the form ('added by admin'):

```
<%= f.hidden_field :created_by_admin, value: true %>
```

Add condition to email validation:

```
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, unless: :created_by_admin?
```

Comment: I was trying the changes you suggested but when I try to update the user that is created by admin. I am not able to save it. This is the error I am getting. No template found for UsersController#update, rendering head :no_content

Comment: How about the other validations? I am not able to create a user if I just add unless: :created_by_admin? to email. I have to uncomment all the validations in user model to create a user by admin.

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU, what is in your UsersController#update?Add condition `unless: :created_by_admin?` to all validations which you want to skip on 'by admin creation'

Comment: unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=' has_secure_password, unless: :created_by_admin? ^  has_secure_password, unless: :created_by_admin? . this is the error I am getting.

Comment: I have a users signup form and once a users signs up he is redirected to users details forms. When an admin adds a user there is no need of user signup form and i have added another form add_user form through which admin adds new user. I have not added UsersController#update for users who are created by admin. There are separate forms for users created by admin and not created by admin.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`attr_accessor`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) in your model, if you don't want any changes to your existing schema.

*models/user.rb*

```
class User
  attr_accessor :with_email_optional

  # Run these validations only if `self.with_email_optional` is not set OR set to `false`
  validates :email,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            unless: :with_email_optional
end
```

And in your users controller for admin (i don't know what that is called in your application):

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.with_email_optional = true
end

private

# To be used in `create` action
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(..., :with_email_optional)
end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f|
  <%= f.hidden_field :with_email_optional, value: f.object.with_email_optional %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I need the option for created by admin in the db.